# Web3: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t

Tags: python, solidity, web3py

When trying to call some view function, for some huge amounts of input values I get the error

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t

For example, bellow produces the error: (The input value is 2*10^24)

> pancakeContract.functions.getAmountsIn(2000000000000000000000000, [w3.toChecksumAddress('0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56'), w3.toChecksumAddress('0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c')]).call()

The contract ABI can be found here:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F#code

Comment: I've the exact same problem. Did you find a solution ? Best regards

Comment: @CodeFlakes Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution yet. In order to temporarily solve my problem, I made a wrapper contract on the BSC that calls the original contract; however, it works with numbers with thirteen less digits. Then, instead of calling the original contract from my python code, I interact with this wrapper one. Still would be happy if you find any better solution.

Comment: I actually don't have the problem anymore. I had this error because I wasn't using the right parameters or they were not of the right type, I'm not sure.  On my code I use 1BNB = 1000000000000000000 WEI and it works, I did not try with bigger amounts. Also I'm using a different syntax which is: contract.functions['getAmountsIn'](X [Y Z]).call()

Comment: @CodeFlakes Yeah, if you use a wrong input for any function, then probably it outputs something so big, thus overflowing. I think I have tried all of the getAmount* functions and got the same error. For numbers with more than 23 digits you will get this error, which is not actually a large number for tokens that worth less than 0.01$, and there are many of them. Even I tried the web3.js and faced the same issue. Now I wonder in which way other projects such as MetaMask are calling such functions.